# Timestamp Skew in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run a pipeline which reads from from a pubsub topic and writes to bigquery. The timestamps are parsed from the topic messages. However I received an error about allowed timestamp skew with a reference to the documentation reproduced below.

> getAllowedTimestampSkew public Duration getAllowedTimestampSkew()
>   Returns the allowed timestamp skew duration, which is the maximum
>   duration that timestamps can be shifted backward in
>   DoFn.Context.outputWithTimestamp(OutputT, org.joda.time.Instant). The
>   default value is Duration.ZERO, in which case timestamps can only be
>   shifted forward to future. For infinite skew, return
>   Duration.millis(Long.MAX_VALUE).

What I want to know is WHY the default allowed skew is zero? Isn't the whole point of Dataflow to deal with late and out-of-order data? And when would the data be shifted to the future?

Answer (score 4):

Dataflow handles late and out-of-order data using a watermark to track up to what point in event time the input is complete. The watermark for PubSub is tracked using knowledge of timestamps on pending PubSub messages. This relies on knowing what timestamps are associated with each PubSub message and each element as it flows through the pipeline. Outputting events with timestamp skew violates this knowledge and can lead to incorrect behavior including needing to re-assign windows using the new timestamps for the rest of the pipeline to behave correctly and/or elements being dropped due to being “too late”.

The blog posts [Streaming 101](http://radar.oreilly.com/2015/08/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101.html) and [Streaming 102](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102) discuss the concepts of watermarks and handling event time in much more detail.

In this case, since you’re using PubSubIO you can take advantage of the fact that it is a built in source and has special logic for tracking a watermark of the event times of messages in the PubSub queue. Put a timestamp label on each of the published messages and then use 
[PubSubIO#timestampLabel](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/PubsubIO.Read#timestampLabel-java.lang.String-) to associate with the event times of the messages.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation when not using PubSubIO?

Comment: Timestamp information is source dependent -- if you're writing your own unbounded source, you can specify what the watermark is at any point in time.